# Как "заремарить" строки в xml разметке?

Tags: java, android

Можно ли "заремарить" строки в xml разметке?
Если да, то как?

Comment: Что такое "заремарить"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Комментарии начинаются с группы символов `<!--` и заканчиваются группой символов `-->`: например, `<!--catalog last updated 2000-11-01-->`.

Answer (score 2):

Быстрые клавиши:

выделить всё, что необходимо закомментить, и нажать shift+ctrl+/

Comment: Удобно. Спасибо.